# Inverse using Adjoint Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Can anyone prove why all these zeros work out when multiplying the matrix A by the adjoint matrix as shown in the link here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L6APsIqyx-k.

I understand and can prove how the determinant of A exists along the diagonal. I just don't know how the zeros work out!

Comment: Looks like the rationale for the zeros is explained in a link with "why?" around 2:30 or so.

Comment: Note that $\operatorname{adj}(A)$ is usually called the _adjugate_ matrix (or _classical_ adjoint). The name adjoint usually denotes the transposed complex conjugate version of $A$.

Comment: It was proved in the sense that it was just an example (a long one). However, I want something more related to matrix properties or finite groups.